# Can you customize / change the spreadsheet ID of a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Can you customize / change the spreadsheet ID of a Google Sheet (ie. the ID string that shows up in the gsheet's URL)?

I ask this because when looking at the docs for the gsheet api's [`create()`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) method and looking at the expected [request body template](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet), I see that one of the fields available is the `spreadsheetId`. Does this mean that I can `create()` a spreadsheet with a specific `spreadsheetId`?

I find the docs for the API request bodies to be unclear about *what* certain fields are and when they are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you customize / change the spreadsheet ID of a Google Sheet

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, no this isn't possible.*

#### More Information:

While the `spreadsheets.create` method does imply that you can select a custom spreadsheet ID when creating a new Spreadsheet, you can see this on the documentation page for the [spreadsheet REST Resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) (emphasis my own):

> **Fields:**
>
> `spreadsheetId`               string
>
> The ID of the spreadsheet. ***This field is read-only.***

As the `spreadsheetId` field is read-only, if one provides an ID to the API on creation, then the field will be ignored and an ID will be generated all the same.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.create | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)
- [REST Resource: spreadsheets | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet)